# EF 6.0 DbContext Generator or EntityObject generator

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, t4

I'm new to EF and still trying to get simple stuff to work correctly using VS2013 & framework 4.5
i
To use `customerBindingSource.DataSource = _context.Customers.Local.ToBindingList();`

I must be working with `EF 6.0 DbContext` code generation item/template but then I can't use custom validation class

```
public partial class Customer
{
    // Property Blocked 
    partial void OnBlockedChanged()
    {

    }
}
```

because  there are No defining declaration found for implementing declaration of partial method 'Winpro.Customer.OnBlockedChanged()

If I add `EF 6.0 EntityObject Generator` then I can use my partial class but can't use

`.Local.To.BindingList()`

because :

`'System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectSet<Winpro.Customer>' does not contain a definition for 'Local' and no extension method 'Local' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectSet<Winpro.Customer>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`

And this is how I declare and use this in my forms :

```
public partial class FormCustomerView : Form
{
    winproContext _context;

    public FormCustomerView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        _context = new winproContext();
    }
    private void FormCustomerView_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        this.locationBindingSource.DataSource = _context.Locations.ToList();
        this.ruleBindingSource.DataSource = _context.Rules.ToList();

        customerBindingSource.DataSource = _context.Customers.Local.ToBindingSource();
        customerBindingSource.AddNew();
    }
       ........
```

Thanks.

Comment: What's your question?